# Call to a member function close() on a non-object - FATAL ERROR

Tags: php

I have an issue that gives me the error that there is `non-object`, but I have created an object to access the function. Where is it am going wrong? It worked in my old wamp version but when I updated I keep getting the error.

```
function readValues() {
    $tablename_organizations = DbManager::getTableName('organizations'); 
    $sql = "SELECT ORGID FROM $tablename_organizations WHERE DEFAULTORG = 1";
    $conn = DbManager::createAdodbConnection();
    $recordSet = &$conn->Execute($sql);
    if ($this->foundSqlError($sql, $conn)) {
        $recordSet->close();
        return false;
    }
```

EDIT: Now, I get error in here

```
function createAdodbConnection($fetchMode = ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC) {
        $self = DbManager::_instance();
        $conn = &ADONewConnection($self->getDsn());
        $conn->SetFetchMode($fetchMode);
        return $conn;
    }
```

Same error

```
Call to a member function SetFetchMode() on a non-object
```

Comment: Where and how is DbManager deinfed? Especially: What are the possible return values of DbManager::Execute()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be `$conn` (connection link) instead of `$recordSet` (SQL query result)

```
$conn->close();
```

Comment: now i get new error similar to above, updated question please check

Answer (score 1):

it should be:-

```
if ($this->foundSqlError($sql, $conn)) {
       $conn->close();
        return false;
    }
```

because to create connection with

```
 $conn = DbManager::createAdodbConnection();
```

so i should be close by `$conn`